# How to secure the API in NestJS, using Firebase Auth gmail in Client?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, jwt, nestjs, restful-authentication

How can we secure the NestJS API endpoints?

**Client**

Android Native Application with Firebase Gmail Auth.

**SERVER**

NestJS Framework with ExpressJS, TypeORM ,MySQL

Our user authenticating by Firebase Auth "Google Auth Provider" and getting UID and storing it on Server. How to protect the POST endpoints.

**Payload**

```
{
  "uid":"adsfasdfasdfas",
  "name":"John",
  "email":"email@example.com",
  "token":"XZExzs2511WSSkl" // How to make this token, and can be validate in Server
}
```

Please suggest, what's the good approach?

Thanks

Comment: You can use an Auth Guard https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#authorization-guard

Answer (score 0):

You should have a read on the chapter on [Authentication in NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication), and use Passport that will make your job easy.